# For a compact set $K\subset \mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$, the eigenvalues of matrices in $K$ form a bounded set

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $K\subset \mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$ be a compact subset. Then I have to show that :

> > All the eigen values of the elements of $K$ form a bounded set.

My work: consider the map $K \to det K$ which is continuous. Image set is compact in $\mathbb C$, hence closed bounded. If $\lambda_i (i=1\ldots,n)$ are the eigenvalues, then $\det K=\prod \lambda_i$ is bounded which in turn  gives $\lambda_i$ bounded.

Is my approach correct? Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Let for real $a$ and $b$ you have $ab=1$. Can you conclude that $a$ is bounded? Of course not.

Comment: also imagine that all the elements of $K$ have at least an eigenvalue equal to zero... you get det(A)=0 and you may not conclude.

Comment: Perhaps you should specify, compact with respect to *what*? What norm/metric/topology are you using on $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$? That would clear up some of the answers, I think.

Answer (score 5):

You can consider a map $K\to \|K\|_2$, where $\|\cdot\|_2$ is a spectral norm of the matrix. This map is continuous (should be an easy exercise), and it has a great property - for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $K$ you have $|\lambda|\le \|K\|_2$.

Comment: I feel like proving the continuity of the spectral norm is more involved than it seems at first glance. In particular, proving this requires a step that is essentially a more complicated version than what is being asked.

Comment: Is converse true of my stated question?

Comment: @MeesdeVries that is very much untrue. In particular: with this approach, we don't need the fact that the eigenvalues depend continuously on the matrix entires, which can be very difficult.

Comment: One question:: Here $A\mapsto \text{(maximum eigen value of}{A^tA)}^{\frac{1}{2}}$ which is continuous and hence the set of eigen values of $A^tA$ is bounded but how to show from above that eigen values of $A$ are bounded

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I don't disagree that this is easier than the *approach* OP tried, but I believe this is more difficult than answering the question OP had.

Comment: @learnmore you can show that if $z$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $|z| \le (\mathrm{maximum\,\,eigenvalue\,\,of} A^TA)^{1/2}$, it is not that difficult. Just take an eigenvector corresponding to $z$ and look what happens with the expression $(Az,Az)$.

Comment: @MeesdeVries we can fall back to a general argument that all norms in linear spaces of finite dimension are equivalent; all you need now is the fact that spectral norm is indeed a norm, which is covered in all textbooks. After that the equivalence of norms gives you the continuity for free.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy, the equivalence of all norms is just another way to say that they are all equivalent in the metrics defined by all others. That general argument is more complicated (because it proves more) than proving what OP asked for.

Comment: @learnmore it a typo; the last phrase should read "Just take an eigenvector $v$ corresponding to $z$ and look what happens with the expression $(Av,Av)$."

Comment: $Av=zv\implies  (Av,Av)=(v,A^TAv)$; Also $(Av,Av)=(zv,zv)=|z|^2(v,v)$

Comment: I have added some steps;Will you please tell how to conclude from here that all eigen values of $A $  are bounded?

Comment: @learnmore now you compare $\frac{(Av,Av)}{\|v\|^2}=\frac{(zv,zv)}{\|v^2\|}=|z|^2$ and $\text{(maximum eigen value of}{A^tA)} = \sup_{w\ne 0} \frac{(A^tAw,w)}{\|w\|^2}$.

Comment: Yes I got it;Thank you so much

Answer (score 4):

Let $||*||$ be any norm on $ \mathbb R^n$ and let $||*||_O$ the matrix norm induced by $||*||$

Since $K$ is compact, $K$ is bounded. Thus, there is $c>0$ such that

$||A||_O \le c$ for all $A \in K$.

Now let  $A \in K$ and let $ \lambda$ be an eigenvalue of $A$. Then there is $x \in \mathbb R^n$ with $Ax= \lambda x$ and $||x||=1$.

We get

$$| \lambda|=|| \lambda x||= ||Ax|| \le ||A||_O*||x||=||A||_O \le c.$$

Comment: The central thing to prove in this argument is that the induced matrix norm is continuous as a function of the *a priori* topology on $\mathbb M_n(\mathbb R)$ -- probably Euclidean? But proving this is more complicated than proving what the question is about directly.

Comment: How ||Ax||≤||A||O∗||x||?

Comment: @MeesdeVries invoking the fact that all finite dimensional normed spaces are topologically equivalent does not seem all that complicated. At the very least, proving that the spectral norm and the Euclidean norm over $M_n$ are equivalent is fairly straightforward.

Comment: Not all eigenvalues have purely real eigenvectors. Consider a matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0\end{pmatrix} $

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I don't disagree (although I think it's more fidgety than you'd expect), but it's more difficult than proving what the original question asked.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is not correct. In fact, $\prod_i \lambda_i$ can be bounded without $\max_i \lambda_i$ being bounded. (Why?)

A better way of going about it is this: for any $A \in \mathbb M_N(\mathbb R)$, any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $A$ is bounded by
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n |A_{i,j}|.
$$

Edit: It is even easier to do this when we take our bound $K$ equal to $n$ times the above sum. In that case, let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of eigenvector $x$, and let $x_i$ be the largest entry of $x$. Then in particular
$$
|\lambda| |x_i| = \left|\sum_{j=1}^n A_{i,j}x_j\right| \leq \sum_{j=1}^n |A_{i,j}||x_j| \leq \sum_{j=1}^n \frac Kn|x_i| = K|x_i|,
$$
hence $|\lambda| \leq K$.

Comment: Is there a quick way to see that this provides an upper bound to the spectral radius?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, I provided a computation for a slightly different bound (I am pretty sure the original bound also works, but the argument requires less carelessness.)

Comment: Very good.  I can see that, if you're working without any foreknowledge about matrix norms, this is the easiest approach

Answer (score 1):

An easy approach for me:

Consider the map $f:K\to \Bbb C$ by $f(x)=\dfrac{x^TAx}{x^Tx}$
which is continuous and hence bounded on $K$.

$\text{Image} f=\{f(x):x\in K\}$ is bounded.

Now if $\lambda $ is an eigen value of $A$ corresponding to eigen vector $v$ then $Av=\lambda v\implies f(v)=\lambda$.

Hence $\lambda \in \text{Image }f$ which is bounded

Comment: $f$ is not a mapping $K \to \mathbb R$. Edit: it is even less a mapping $K \to \mathbb C$. It takes a vector as an argument, and $K$ is a space of (real) matrices.

Comment: @MeesdeVries the argument is written incorrectly, but the idea is to use the numerical radius as an upper bound for the absolute value of eigenvalues

Comment: How should I frame this argument correctly@Omnomnomnom;Please suggest some required edits

Comment: @learnmore actually, I'm not even sure that my idea is what you're going for.  At the very least, you should notice Mees's objection.  Is $f$ supposed to be a function on matrices, or on vectors?

Comment: Yes that was my idea but I ended up doing it wrongly@Omnomnomnom